# Game theory software

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, software

I was wondering what software/libraries everyone uses to simulate games? For instance finding the Nash Equilibrium. I see that Gambit is a popular one, but I was wondering if there are any other good ones? (good=robust, reliable and not slow)

Comment: I would also like to specify that I'm specifically looking to manipulate data programatically.

Answer (score 6):

I have used [gambit](http://gambit.sourceforge.net/gambit15/gui.html) (python) in the past and could recommend it. It also includes a small [GUI](http://gambit.sourceforge.net/gambit15/gui.html) which makes things very intuitive.

R also has [GameTheory](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GameTheory/index.html) if you prefer this platform instead

Answer (score 5):

[**Game theory explorer (GTE)**](http://gte.csc.liv.ac.uk/index/) offers a web-based solver that searches for Nash equilibria of the inputted games. [Its documentation](http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/stengel/TEXTE/largeongte.pdf) highlights the main differences between GTE and Gambit:

> Gambit has been developed over the course of nearly 25 years and
>   presents a library of solution algorithms, formats for storing games,
>   ways to program the creation of games with the help of the Python
>   programming language, and a GUI for creating game trees. It is
>   open-source software that is free to use and that can be extended by
>   anyone. Given the mature state of Gambit and the joint research
>   interests and close contacts with its developers, it is clear that any
>   improvements offered by GTE should eventually be integrated into
>   Gambit.
>
> [...]
>
> The main difference of GTE to Gambit is the provided access to the
>   software and the user interface. In terms of access, Gambit needs to
>   be downloaded and installed; it is offered on the main personal
>   computing platforms Windows, Linux or Mac. Getting the program to run
>   may require some patience and technical experience with software
>   installations, which may present a “barrier to entry” for its use. In
>   contrast, GTE is started in a web browser via the web address
>   http://www.gametheoryexplorer.org. All interaction with the software
>   is via the browser interface. The created games and their output can
>   be saved as files by the user on their local computer. This avoids the
>   technical hurdles of installing software on the user side, and
>   simplifies updating the software.